# How can a macOS SMB share be mounted on Linux so that symbolic links can be created on it?

Tags: linux, macos, samba, smb, cifs

There is lots of conflicting information about it and it seems to depend a lot on the versions of various modules, and specific mount options.

I'm **not** looking for the symlink "emulation" (**mfsymlinks**), but an **actual symbolic link** should be created on the macOS machine when I do something like

```
root@linux:/mnt/macOS# ln -s foo bar
```

from the Linux machine that mounts the macOS SMB share.

Trying this yields the following error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'bar': Operation not supported
```

From everything that I can gather on Google, this should be possible in recent Samba and SMB versions, i.e. it should support creating actual symbolic links on the remote filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clients can't create symlinks on Samba share](https://superuser.com/questions/1337257/clients-cant-create-symlinks-on-samba-share)

Comment: Not a duplicate -- the other question deals with the "emulation" that I try to avoid (mfsymlinks)