# symlinks on Samba share created by linux client (mfsymlink) not working on server

Tags: network-shares, samba, symbolic-link, cifs

On my mounted Samba share I can create a symlink from a linux client by simple

```
ln -s hello.txt hello.sl
```

This works for the client (on linux) when 'mfsymlinks' option is enabled, but the symlink doesn't work when accesing from a windows client (or on the server itslef)!

How can I create a symbolic link on a Samba share working on the server?

This problem was also mentioned in an answer from Murmanfurt to this question:

[Clients can't create symlinks on Samba share](https://superuser.com/questions/1337257/clients-cant-create-symlinks-on-samba-share/1689464?r=Saves_AllUserSaves#1689464)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected result when `mfsymlinks` is used. The entire point of this option is that symlink creation is *emulated* via regular files with special contents so that they could be created on symlink-incapable servers; i.e. it's the opposite of what you want.

With SMBv1 (CIFS), symlink support was part of "CIFS Unix Extensions". Those are active by default when a Linux client mounts a Samba-hosted share, but they only work with SMBv1 which is generally considered 'deprecated'. (Partly due to Windows-specific security issues, partly due to general protocol-level issues.)

Your mount most likely uses SMBv3, which has "POSIX extensions" as the equivalent, but as far as I know, those are not yet 100% implemented in Linux and Samba. If you have a very recent version of Linux kernel on the client and a very recent Samba version on the server, it should work if manually enabled (and if you *disable* 'mfsymlinks' of course); with older versions AFAIK it won't work just yet.

Though on a related note, I've actually heard that Samba's plan is to *not* support server-side symlink creation at all, due to the security issues that it frequently leads to (e.g. a POSIX-capable client can create a symlink, then connect again as if it were non-POSIX-capable, and trick the server into following that symlink). So you might have to switch to NFSv4 instead.